# Why code is not being executed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following method in a class that extends WebView

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"WEBVIEW - Start Load");

    static BOOL isFirstLaunch = YES;

    if (isFirstLaunch) {
        isFirstLaunch = NO;

    } else {
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"localStorage.states = '[{},{\"name\":\"Dashboard\"}]'"];
    }
      // webView connected
    webviewTimeout = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kWebViewLoadTimeOut target:self selector:@selector(webViewTimeout) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

the `static` declaration plus the `if else` is jumped when program is executing. I notice this when in Xcode debugger.
I can't see anything wrong with my code. I though it could be due to `static BOOL` variable declaration inside the method, I declared it out of any blocks in the .m file. but the `if else` still not being execute. I also tried to put the code in a ViewController class before loading my WebView, but the code mentioned still not being executed. What I'm missing here?

To be clearer: I notice that code is not being executed with Xcode Debugger. I put a breakpoint in the method beginning ,in `NSLog`, if I put any breakpoint in any part that is inside `if else` or in the `static` variable declaration, seems to ignore it, and no break is done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Please explain how you investigated this, such as breakpoints, `NSLog`s etc

Comment: Also, are you building with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Did you specify the `delegate` for the webview? This is a `UIWebViewDelegate` method.

Comment: @Rob, I forgot to mention but this class also implements UIWebViewDelegate (I didn't project this)

Comment: Where is the code that causes webViewDidStartLoad to be invoked? One of the LoadXXX methods that you need to call.

Comment: @user1118321 the problem was the optimizations. I try two approaches: forced the optimization not to work there and the code was executed. And turned it off and code was also executed. Please post your answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler optimizations can sometimes confuse the debugger. They can rearrange instructions or even remove code. Turning them off can make it easier to step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have done the following:

```
// set yourself as the delegate
webView.delegate = self;

// begin loading
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"http://www.someURLHere.com"]];
```